# Find midpoint of street geometry,with grid lines

Tags: spatial-database, oracle-dbms

Currently my application displays street name in middle of whole street, but when we use grids,we want to display street name in middle of street under grid,I want to calculate midpoint of street geometry,I have start point and length of street,I could not use sdo_centroid.Please help in finding midpoint using length?

Comment: What application?

Comment: Its autocad application,I need solution oracle spatial query,I can get intersection between grid and street,need to find centre of street in that intersection